# How to get Cinergy HTC Stick (ID 0ccd:00b2) with DVB-T running?

Tags: 12.10, usb, kernel, dvb, dvb-t

I try to get the Cinergy HTC Stick (`ID 0ccd:00b2`) with DVB-T running.
Normally is should work with Ubuntu 12.10 (kernel 3.5.x) out of box. But I only get DVB-C running. If I try scan on DVB-T I get only errors (like of Me TV):

```
stephan@coppi:~$ me-tv
Me TV 1.3.7
11/14/2012 16:39:02: Device: 'DRXK DVB-C DVB-T' (DVB-C) at "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0"
11/14/2012 16:39:25: Frontend::tune_to(570000000)
11/14/2012 16:39:25: Frontend::tune_to(594000000)
11/14/2012 16:39:25: Frontend::tune_to(730000000)
11/14/2012 16:39:25: Frontend::tune_to(762000000)
```

syslog out:

```
Nov 14 16:39:00 coppi kernel: [ 9162.191371] tda18271: performing RF tracking filter calibration
Nov 14 16:39:02 coppi kernel: [ 9163.886308] tda18271: RF tracking filter calibration complete
Nov 14 16:39:25 coppi kernel: [ 9187.170324] usb 2-5: DVB: adapter 0 frontend 0 symbol rate 0 out of range (870000..11700000)
Nov 14 16:39:25 coppi kernel: [ 9187.179694] usb 2-5: DVB: adapter 0 frontend 0 symbol rate 0 out of range (870000..11700000)
Nov 14 16:39:25 coppi kernel: [ 9187.188615] usb 2-5: DVB: adapter 0 frontend 0 symbol rate 0 out of range (870000..11700000)
Nov 14 16:39:25 coppi kernel: [ 9187.193045] usb 2-5: DVB: adapter 0 frontend 0 symbol rate 0 out of range (870000..11700000)
```

Other tools like Me TV also not work.

**Now some system information**

Ubuntu 12.10 (fully updated)

*syslog out on plug the device*

```
Nov 14 16:43:15 coppi kernel: [ 9417.237673] usb 2-5: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.371866] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0ccd, idProduct=00b2
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.371877] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.371884] usb 2-5: Product: Cinergy_HTC_Stick
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.371889] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: TERRATEC
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.371894] usb 2-5: SerialNumber: 02?TERRATE
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.372344] em28xx: New device TERRATEC Cinergy_HTC_Stick @ 480 Mbps (0ccd:00b2, interface 0, class 0)
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.372348] em28xx: Audio Vendor Class interface 0 found
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.372352] em28xx: Video interface 0 found
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.372355] em28xx: DVB interface 0 found
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.372490] em28xx #0: chip ID is em2884
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-5"
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.425876] em28xx #0: Identified as Terratec Cinergy HTC Stick (card=82)
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.426004] em28xx #0: Config register raw data: 0x62
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.426008] em28xx #0: I2S Audio (3 sample rates)
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.426011] em28xx #0: No AC97 audio processor
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.453233] em28xx #0: v4l2 driver version 0.1.3
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.489410] em28xx #0: V4L2 video device registered as video0
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.489884] em28xx-audio.c: probing for em28xx Audio Vendor Class
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.489889] em28xx-audio.c: Copyright (C) 2006 Markus Rechberger
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9417.489892] em28xx-audio.c: Copyright (C) 2007-2011 Mauro Carvalho Chehab
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9418.009366] drxk: status = 0x639260d9
Nov 14 16:43:16 coppi kernel: [ 9418.009376] drxk: detected a drx-3926k, spin A3, xtal 20.250 MHz
Nov 14 16:43:20 coppi kernel: [ 9422.069556] DRXK driver version 0.9.4300
Nov 14 16:43:20 coppi kernel: [ 9422.098506] drxk: frontend initialized.
Nov 14 16:43:20 coppi kernel: [ 9422.098529] tda18271 5-0060: creating new instance
Nov 14 16:43:20 coppi kernel: [ 9422.103989] TDA18271HD/C2 detected @ 5-0060
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi kernel: [ 9422.346390] DVB: registering new adapter (em28xx #0)
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi kernel: [ 9422.346406] usb 2-5: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (DRXK DVB-C DVB-T)...
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi kernel: [ 9422.349066] em28xx #0: Successfully loaded em28xx-dvb
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi kernel: [ 9422.350139] Registered IR keymap rc-nec-terratec-cinergy-xs
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi kernel: [ 9422.350382] input: em28xx IR (em28xx #0) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-5/rc/rc3/input20
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi kernel: [ 9422.350492] rc3: em28xx IR (em28xx #0) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-5/rc/rc3
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi pulseaudio[1979]: [pulseaudio] source.c: Default and alternate sample rates are the same.
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi rtkit-daemon[1464]: Successfully made thread 17873 of process 1979 (n/a) owned by '20016' RT at priority 5.
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi rtkit-daemon[1464]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Nov 14 16:43:21 coppi kernel: [ 9422.633025] em28xx #0: submit of audio urb failed
```

*dvbsnoop the device*

```
stephan@coppi:~$ dvbsnoop -s feinfo
dvbsnoop V1.4.50 -- http://dvbsnoop.sourceforge.net/ 

---------------------------------------------------------
FrontEnd Info...
---------------------------------------------------------

Device: /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0

Basic capabilities:
    Name: "DRXK DVB-C DVB-T"
    Frontend-type:       QAM (DVB-C)
    Frequency (min):     47000.000 kHz
    Frequency (max):     864000.000 kHz
    Frequency stepsiz:   166.667 kHz
    Frequency tolerance: 0.000 kHz
    Symbol rate (min):     0.870000 MSym/s
    Symbol rate (max):     11.700000 MSym/s
    Symbol rate tolerance: 0 ppm
    Notifier delay: 0 ms
    Frontend capabilities:
        auto inversion
        FEC 1/2
        FEC 2/3
        FEC 3/4
        FEC 5/6
        FEC 7/8
        FEC AUTO
        QAM 16
        QAM 32
        QAM 64
        QAM 128
        QAM 256
        auto transmission mode
        auto guard interval
        auto hierarchy

Current parameters:
    Frequency:  0.000 kHz
    Inversion:  OFF
    Symbol rate:  0.000000 MSym/s
    FEC:  none
    Modulation:  QPSK
```

**What I already did:**

- using `git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git` to build new modules from head (no change)
- trying on Windows (bubu). it work device is OK
- scan channels with working device and try to use them (nop)
- playing a bit with source to set maybe DVB-T on first position (without deeply knowledge) (no effect)

I hope anyone has an idea.
If you need more Informations give me a command.
I'm also happy to try something.

Answer (score 3):

OK, sorry for this extreme short answer.

I wanted to help someone else, listing all the frontends of his DVB receivers. So I installed the dvb-tools.

```
sudo apt-get install dvb-tools
```

I tried dvb-fe-tool, but it could only show details about one adapter at a time. But I noticed the last line of the output to be:

```
$ dvb-fe-tool
...
Supported delivery systems: [DVBC/ANNEX_A] DVBC/ANNEX_C DVBT
```

After reading the help page I tried this option (-d, --set-delsys=PARAMS  set delivery system) to change the delivery system.

```
dvb-fe-tool -d DVBT
```

And it worked. Now I could scan for the DVB-T channels and watch them. DVB-C didn't work any more as expected. You don't need to unplug the stick but you need to switch the antenna.

```
dvb-fe-tool -d DVBC/ANNEX_A
```

Use this to switch back to DVB-C or just un- and replug the receiver.
If you have more than one DVB receiver, use the option -a to choose the correct adapter.

In the end it didn't help me list all the frontends, but switching to DVB-T is a nice byproduct.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu anon! Thanks for posting a more elaborate answer! I just wanted to let you know though, that you can always [edit] your answer by clicking the `edit` button right underneath the text of your answer. So you could have done that on your other answer and expanded it, instead of posting another answer =). However, no worries, we'll just delete the other answer (I'll flag it for moderators to do so)! Also, you should consider registering an account in Ask Ubuntu, and contribute more =D!

Answer (score 1):

It works as DVB-T on Kafeine by running the following command line, after installing w_scan :

```
w_scan -ft -cAT -x > initial-tuning-data.txt
```

Then, you must rename `initial-tuning-data-txt` as `scanfile.dvb` and copy the file (or replace if its already there) in your `~/.kde/apps/kaffeine` and also in `/usr/share/kde4/apps/kaffeine`

It works but its not perfect, because I always have to do this operation everytime I restart my computer or plug the USB stick again once it has been removed. However, it's no longer necessary to re-name and copy once afgain the files in the described folders as explained above.

When you're done, open Kafeine, click on 5 Digital TV. Then, click on Television thumbnail, choose Configure TV, select Peripheral 1, it should show your device with DVB-T enabled. It in list select automatic search. When done, click on Television thumbnail again and choose Channels. Start scanning for channels and when it's done, move them to the other (left) column. Choose a channel and enjoy.

Comment: It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try either:

[ambrosa / DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0](https://github.com/ambrosa/DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0)

[tmair / DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0](https://github.com/tmair/DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0)

I have a **Terratec** *Cinergy TStick+* (ID 0ccd:00d7).

I have so far tried various methods, on both **12.04 LTS** and **12.10** (both latest update/kernel). So far, unable to recognise device.

*However, your device is not quite so new and may work ..*

---

**UPDATE**

Neither of these worked for me, and I instead had to use **media build** driver.

[How to Obtain, Build and Install V4L-DVB Device Drivers](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers)

The device now works with fine with **Kaffeine**, but not with **Me TV** ..

*(still testing)*